# Proxy error: DNS lookup failure for

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dns-lookup

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: www.******.com
```

This is appearing sometimes like every 5 minutes or so. Sometimes the website load completly, sometimes the CSS don't load and some images are missing.

I've set the nameserver in the resolv.conf to

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

But it doesn't seems to help. How could this happens every 5 minutes or so and last for 1 or 2 minutes before coming back ok?

Comment: Is this a server you control?

Comment: Now yes but was controlled by another tech guy last week. He went bankrupt and we have taken control of his clients and servers